# Non-linear regression with a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, ai-design, regression

I have to perform a regression on three curves as shown in the following plot. Here, `accA` (y-axis) is the dependent variable, and `w` (x-axis) is the independent variable. The sum of the three curves adds up to 1.

To perform regression for the three curves, I would like to use a neural network. What architecture/set-up should I use for this task?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Just to clarify, what exactly do you want to predict here? Do you want to predict the value for each of the 3 curves individually?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like to fit three curves individually, basically, but in a way that the sums of their ouput always adds up to 1, for each choice of the variable w. I would like to use a neural network, instead of performing a regression manually.

Comment: @Fq00 It looks like you want to do time series prediction maybe? So the real goal is to predict the _next_ value of of the 3 accA functions, given the past values of accA (and maybe w)?